# How to limit number of files allowed to be uploaded using <p:fileUpload>

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

How to limit number of files allowed to be uploaded using  in JSF 2 + primefaces application. Attribute 'filelimit' was there in primeface 3.3 but I am using primefaces 3.4

Comment: INMO , your best bet is `auto="true"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the fileLimit option has been removed in Issue [3618](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3618)

As mentioned in the comments use a counter in the backing bean and either discard extra files or add a FacesMessage to notify the user that maximum fileLimit has been reached.

Code sample:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileUploadController {

    private final static int MAX_NUM_FILES = 3;
    private List<UploadedFile> uploadedFiles;
    private int counter = 0;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        uploadedFiles = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();
    }


    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        if (counter < MAX_NUM_FILES) {
            uploadedFiles.add(event.getFile());
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            counter ++;       
        }
        else {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "File Upload Limit Reached ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is not uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }

    }
}
```